# How to update ACL access of AWS S3 object for large volume of data?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have more than 42 million objects in the S3 bucket, here I need to update the objects with ACL Full-Control. Currently, i am updating through AWS Command -

> aws s3api get-object-acl --bucket XXX --key XX

The issue is I can update a max of 60K objects per day So someone can help to suggest any other way here?